# How can I display 'è' with mathJax?

Tags: mathjax, diacritics, anki

I am using Anki, an app for flashcards, and I'm trying to write text with accents on a card with mathJax.

I tried to put directly this character in my text, but it was smaller than the other characters.

I also tried to write `` \`e ``, but it was definitely oversized.

Of course `\grave{e}` doesn't suit because I want it to be text, but it has the same effect as `` \`e ``.

Additionally, I can't import extensions since there is no apparent way to do so with Anki.

Is there another way to write accents ?

Comment: have you tried the unicode extension ? https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/unicode.html

Comment: I edited my question, I can't import extensions.